# OS X Lion and Mercurial: Wrong architecture of socket.so

Tags: python, sockets, mercurial, osx-lion, powerpc

my Mac runs Lion (10.7.3) and I've recently installed Mercurial with the respective binary installer for 10.7 provided on the [official Mercurial website](http://mercurial.selenic.com/downloads/). Now each time I want to clone an arbitrary repository (from Bitbucket, in my case), I get the following error message:

> dlopen(/usr/local/bin/socket.so, 2): no suitable image found.
>     Did find: /usr/local/bin/socket.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture!

If I do `file /usr/local/bin/socket.so` I get a surprising response:

> /usr/local/bin/socket.so: Mach-O bundle **ppc**

This is very strange since Lion does not support any PPC code anymore. I just did an upgrade from 10.6.8 to 10.7.3 some days ago. It seems that some now incompatible files were not removed during the upgrade process.

Before I installed the newest Mercurial version, there had already been an older version in the same directory `/usr/local/bin` which got overwritten. Perhaps some necessary files failed to be upgraded successfully? The `socket.so` file is from October 2010, so it obviously does not belong to Mercurial itself. But I don't know whether the older version worked properly as it is my first day today using Mercurial.

What shall I do now? Shall I uninstall Mercurial again and compile it from source? Which functionality is provided by `socket.so` anyway and how could I get a version with the correct architecture?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing Mercurial with MacPorts. I did and haven't had any trouble.

http://www.macports.org/

https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/devel/mercurial/Portfile